# Get the name and value of all cookies

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I'm trying to get all cookies and so far found nothing using Google and other topics.

What I have tried so far:

```
If (Request.Cookies().Count > 0) Then
    sss.Visible = True
    sss.InnerHtml = Request.Cookies().Count
End If
```

I can get the `Cookies().Count` and return a number, but my goal is get the name and value of all cookies. I have no idea what I should use. I'm good in PHP but forced to do this via .NET and can't find something like `var_dump($_COOKIE);` in VB.NET. Any ideas?

Comment: So what is your question? How to iterate over a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If (Request.Cookies.Count > 0) Then
   sss.Visible = True
   Dim i as Ingeter
   For i = 0 To (Request.Cookies.Count - 1)
        sss.InnerHtml = sss.InnerHtml + Request.Cookies.Get(i).Name + " = " + Request.Cookies.Get(i).Value + vbCrLf
   Next
End If
```

Comment: First, thanks for your respond. i used your codes, but get an error `BC30451: Name 'i' is not declared.` i used `Dim i As Integer` it solved but  get another error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: change for loop to this: For i = 1 To Request.Cookies.Count

Comment: still same error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.` on this line `sss.InnerHtml = sss.InnerHtml + Request.Cookies.Get(i).Name + " = " + Request.Cookies.Get(i).Value + vbCrLf`